AWS Athena SQL - Multiplying the constant number to existing data
I am trying to multiply the existing value with some constant value o.1876. the output of the data is looks like
sales_agg

0.01314717
1.46E-04
0.00236974
0.02031013
0.01421709
0.25651208
0.10146865
0.00435217
0.01827912
0.12998486

i just need to mutiply the constant values to existing data and bring to a another column in sql query. tried with Cast Int but no luck. i can ignore the non numeric data in the list and multiply only with proper numeric data.

If the answers below do not meet your requirements, please Edit your Question to show us sample sample Input data (that would be in the table) and the Output data that would you like to see from the query.

Think of the values in a SELECT as being a formula. You can therefore use:
select
  sales_agg * .1876,
  other_column
from table_name


Strange ! I tried this earlier but i got a strange output. now the same is working fine.

In AWS Athena SQL, multiplying a constant number with existing data can be achieved using a straightforward query. For example, to multiply a column by a constant, use:
SELECT column_name * constant_value AS new_column FROM table_name;

This operation scales the data, allowing for various analytical tasks and insights.
